# i find a UIWebView' bug

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

i have a simple viewController to show a web page like this:
WebViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
      _webView.delegate = self;
      [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://estore-cn.pandora.net/Bracelets-1/"]]];
      [self.view addSubview: _webView];
 }
```

and in main view controller

```
- (void)webShow {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: [WebViewController new] 
animated:YES];
}
```

when i pop the webViewController, my main thread be blocked! and i step into thread stack when it been dead lock
[screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InxzC.png)
i guess the url i request has something wrong, could somebody help me~

Comment: Are you pushing the view controller on main thread?

Comment: @Kamil.S  yes, in main thread

Comment: other url is ok, so i gruss the url has something wrong.

Comment: WebViewController created with storyboard or xib?

Comment: @karthikeyan no, i use code

Comment: Please provide a demo which can reproduce the problem.